# Impossible to handle cache in iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, swift, caching, nsurlrequest

I have been struggling for days with handling cache in my app. I created several new app to try the features but I can't make anything work.

For instance, when I try to clear cache, nothing is cleared and all the new web requests I make keep using saved data.

Example of code used:
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()

As anything changed in iOS 8.4?

Thanks

Comment: I know it's not really solving your problem but AFNetworking is good. That definitely still clears cache.

Comment: How are you making the requests?  Directly with NSURLConnection/NSURLSession, or using a web view?

Comment: BTW, the reason I asked that is that NSURLSession objects don't necessarily use the shared cache.